Full outer join but matching only first occurrence
I have table A:
 ID  Date    Amount  TimeRef
 ---------------------------
 xx  29/Jan   10      123
 xx  29/Jan   10      345

And table B:
 ID   Date     Amount  UIQ
 ---------------------------
 xx   29/Jan    10     45678
 xy   29/Jan    10     45670

I want to perform a full outer join on table A and B based on ID, Date and Amount. This results in the following table:
ID   Date    Amount TimeRef ID   Date    Amount   UIQ
----------------------------------------------------
xx   29/Jan   10    123     xx   29/Jan   10    45678
xx   29/Jan   10    345     xx   29/Jan   10    45678
Null  Null    Null   Null   xy   29/Jan   10    45670

However, the result I want is when the ID, Date and Amount are identical in Table A, I want to only match the first occurrence in Table A based on the lowest 'TimeRef':
ID   Date    Amount TimeRef ID   Date    Amount   UIQ
------------------------------------------------------
xx   29/Jan   10    123     xx   29/Jan   10    45678
xx   29/Jan   10    345     Null  Null    Null   Null ---> Returns Null as the first entry has been matched.
Null  Null    Null   Null   xy   29/Jan   10    45670

I tried to use the following code but its not getting me the correct answer and I think Table A should be partitioned not Table B.
SELECT *
FROM #tableA t1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         ID, amount, [date],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,amount, [date] ORDER BY [date]) AS rm
     FROM #tableB t2) AS t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
                            AND t1.amount = t2.amount
                            AND t1.date = t2.date
WHERE 
    t2.rm = 1
    


Can you have dupes on the "right" side? ie. TableB

I'd try the opposite order. I.e. First FULL OUTER JOIN, then use ROW_NUMBER() in the result.

You want to join on ID, amount and date. You want a full outer join. That means that there can be rows in tableA that have no match in tableB and rows in tableB that have no match in tableA. Yes? And there can be multiple rows for the same key (ID, amount and date) in tableA, but only one row per key in tableB? Is all this correct?

I.e. add more sample table data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

@ThorstenKettner Yes this is correct

Table B has no dupes @siggemannen

if you calculate row_number() over table 1 in a subquery you can add: table1.rn = 1 in the full join which should remove the table2 from the right side

Its a little hard to see the rational in this result, although I'm sure its possible. But how is this result useful? For instance, your final result in the above, you don't have any possible primary key and repeated columns. Is it possible that two queries would be more useful - one to show the results of the A->B relationship, and another to show the result of the B->A relationship.

So, you have t1 and t2 and you want to match t1 and t2 records by a criteria that is met, and if so, then only match the first with the first, the second with the second, etc.
Consider this query:
SELECT <your columns of interest here>, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY <your stuff here>) AS row_index
FROM t1

Here you get all the columns you want, + row_index, which signifies the index of the row over the partition you have given. Consider further the same thing for t2:
SELECT <your columns of interest here>, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY <your stuff here>) AS row_index
FROM t2

you may of course vary the columns as you like
SELECT <your columns of interest here>
FROM (
    SELECT <your columns of interest here>, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY <your stuff here>) AS row_index
    FROM t1
) t1_results
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT <your columns of interest here>, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY <your stuff here>) AS row_index
    FROM t2
)
ON <your criteria here> AND t1.row_index = t2.row_index;

which will do a match for you, but will only match a record with another if the criteria you have is true as well as row_index being matched as well.

Something like this perhaps?
WITH table1 AS (
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    VALUES  (N'xx', N'29/Jan', 10, 123)
    ,   (N'xx', N'29/Jan', 10, 345)
) t (ID,Date,Amount,TimeRef)
)
, table2 AS (
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'xx', N'29/Jan', 10, 45678)
    ,   (N'xy', N'29/Jan', 10, 45670)
) t (ID,Date,Amount,UIQ)
)
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   row_number() OVER(partition BY id, date, amount ORDER BY timeref) AS sort
    FROM    table1 t
    ) x
FULL JOIN table2 x2
    ON  x2.ID = x.ID
    AND x2.Date = x.Date
    AND x2.Amount = x.amount
    and x.sort = 1

The full join removes the duplicates from the right side because only the first row will get the match from the "right side".
